# Is it possible to create a .msi installer for dockerized angular plus django web application?

Tags: django, angular, docker

I have a web application (angular+django) running locally in Docker. Is it possible to create an executable version of the application for windows i.e distributable Docker image that could be installed in windows? I do not want the end-user to install docker and run the docker commands, it should be like normal software installation. How should I proceed in this case, if not, any alternative solution possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i don't think any option available to run docker image without installing docker locally in that case you can create executable `.exe` the file of your python project and run it on windows.

here one example : https://algotronics.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/dj2exe/

you can check for pyinstaller : http://www.pyinstaller.org/